# Removing excess spacing for Masonry container using fluid layout

Tags: html, css, jquery-masonry, fluid-layout

I'm trying to create an image gallery using Masonry and the images are re-ordered when the browser is resized.

However, as I am using a fixed width of 150px for the thumbnail images (hence actual large image file is not loaded), but I'm unable to remove the access spacing for the sides of the image container as it will scale based on the screen size as percentage is used for the width.

The site layout is as shown below:

[Layout](https://www.dropbox.com/s/izmahvpudkam6e9/layout.png)

[Actual Layout](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vkw7q3b2ji44u3u/layout_space.png)

Note that there's excess spacing on the right of the image container. In summary,

1. How do I make the container scale to the size of Masonry image grid, as the image container is calculated based on width via percentage?
2. Does it make sense to fix the image to a width of 150 px? If not, which is the preferred method of displaying thumbnails for screens with varying sizes?

#### html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/reset.css" />

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="/static/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    </head>
        <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- the header and navigation -->
            <div id="header">
                <div id="navigation">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Navigation1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Navigation2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>     
            </div>
            <!-- the content -->
            <div id="content">
        <!--- Image container -->
            <div id="gallery_container">
               <ul>
                 <li>
                    <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8001/media/images/d4RYJ4U_1.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8001/media/images/hJLK7.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8001/media/images/vx7IB5M.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8001/media/images/9wMgVOw.png" />
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        <!--Articles sidebar -->
            <div id="sidebar">
                <p>Sidebar</p>
            </div>           
        <!-- the footer -->
            <div id="footer">
                <p>Footer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
        var columns;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#gallery_container').masonry({
                    gutter: 12,
                    itemSelector: '#gallery_container ul li img',
                    columnWidth: 150         
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### css

```
#wrapper {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 96%; 
}
#header {
    margin-right: 1.0416667%; /* 10 div 960 */
    margin-left: 1.0416667%; /* 10 div 960 */
    width: 97.9166667%; /* 940 div 960 */
    background-color: #779307;
}
#navigation {
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    margin-top: 26px;
    margin-left: -1.0416667%; /* 10 div 960 */
    padding-right: 1.0416667%; /* 10 div 960 */
    padding-left: 1.0416667%; /* 10 div 960 */
    width: 97.9166667%; /* 940 div 960 */
}
#navigation ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 2.6595745%; /* 25 div 940 */
}    
#navigation ul li a {
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 42px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Arial, "Lucida Grande", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 27px;
    color: black;
}
#content {
    margin-top: 58px;
    margin-right: 1.0416667%; /* 10 div 960 */
    float: right;
    background-color: #dedede;
    width: 72.7083333%; /* 698 div 960 */
}
#sidebar {
    border-right-color: #e8e8e8;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 2px;
    margin-top: 58px;
    padding-right: 1.0416667%; /* 10 div 960 */
    margin-right: 1.0416667%; /* 10 div 960 */
    float: left;
    width: 22.7083333%; /* 218 div 960 */
    background-color: #fe9c00;
}
#footer {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 1.0416667%; /* 10 div 960 */
    margin-left: 1.0416667%; /* 10 div 960 */
    clear: both;
    width: 97.9166667%; /* 940 div 960 */
    background-color: #663300;
}
#gallery_container {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #302200;
}
#gallery_container ul li {
    display: inline;
}
#gallery_container ul li img {
    padding-top: 10px;  
}
```

Comment: Would be easier if you created a jsfiddle of this so we could play about with it but a first guess would be to try making #gallery_container display: inline-block so it doesn't stretch to the full width of it's parent.

Comment: Hi Billy, jsfiddle created here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/P9S2z/)

Answer (score 0):

I think your fiddle isn't working properly... Anyway, there is the option `"isFitWidth": true` to hint masonry to fill all the horizontal space. Try it.